# xml give me the old result when i refresh the result to new in vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

This code is to view the content of the file in the ftp but when i delete the file and upload file with the same name with different in the content it will gave my the old content

This is the code

```
       URL = "ftp://ftp.example.com/kll.vbs"
       Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
       xml.Open "GET", URL, False, "Yourusername", "Yourpassword"
       xml.Send
       ss= xml.responsetext
       WScript.Echo (ss)
```

Comment: can any body edit the code to fix the problem ??

Comment: it isn't the code that's the problem. Microsoft.XMLHTTP uses caching.  You need to figure out a way around that (check internet options on the PC you're using, or use a different methodology besides XMLHTTP).

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a cache issue.

You could consider using WinHTTP instead.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925(v=vs.85).aspx

Since you're using FTP as the protocol, the above may not be best.

You could also try: xml.setRequestHeader(‘Pragma’, ‘Cache-Control: no-cache’);
You're using an API that enables caching.  Again, it might handle FTP differently.

Comment: i dont want external programs i am just want to fix this issue in the code (view the content of the file in the ftp but when i delete the file and upload file with the same name with different in the content it will gave my the old content) you will not believe but try and you will see